# IOS incorrect border width rendering

Tags: html, ios, css

I set the border width of these input boxes to 1px. However, for some reason on ios, the top border looks bigger than it should be ( regardless of browser ).

[image: (border on ios)]

On any other kind of device, the border looks fine.

[image: (border on non-ios device )]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">
   <title>ios rendering test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<style media="screen">
  input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5%;
  }
</style>
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="" value="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="" value="lastname">
  <input type="text" name="" value="email">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="subscribe">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: none;` or `background-clip: padding-box;`? Googling for something similar to **ios input shadow** would have brought you to a dozen pages with solutions for that.

Comment: This did the trick! thanks!

-webkit-appearance: none;

Comment: Be careful with `-webkit-appearance: none;` though. It shouldn't be used for general `input` selector, but rather on a class. It does a lot more than what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an **iOS** `input` being targeted, you'll need to remove the default styles using `-webkit-appearance: none;`

### Your Code

```
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Add this */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

[Here is an article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/) with more information about the `appearance` tags.